# Dell Vostro 14 5000 Series

Tags: laptop, drivers

I am installing windows 10 pro on a new Vostro 14 5000 Series and after installing all the drivers from the dell site I ran into some problems with:
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9D3A&CC_0780
and
APCI\VEN_INT&DEV_344B

I called dell support but they where unable to assist me
I have allso searched google but found nothing useful
However I might have missed something.

Comment: Driver problems for which devices...? Look in device manager and list which ones are having the issues?  We don't know Dell codes.

Comment: PCI Simple Communications Controller

Comment: and a unknown device

Comment: Well hard for us to help with the unknown device but did you search Dell's website for the PCI Controller driver? Usually they bundle their drivers together in a pack so might have to search hard.  Also did you check if Windows could find one? You could luck out that way too.

Comment: I searched dell and google for the last 3 days

Comment: Is there any tool to auto detect and install the drivers?

Comment: This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Have you installed all the Windows Updates and used Dell drivers for this equipment? The Windows 7 drivers are likely not the same as Windows 10. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: See this page, Unknown Device Identifier http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html

Comment: For future reference, unknown device ID's come up easily in Google if you drop the "PCI/" bit from the front. Second result on [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=VEN_8086%26DEV_9D3A%26CC_0780&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) reveals that it's the management engine driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9D3A` stands for `Intel(R) Management Engine Interface`. The latest version can be found [here](http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=352&func=startdown&id=2107&lang=en).